# awesome_nested_set How to not select a parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I just got [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) put in place and all is working well. I converted over from acts_as_tree using `Category.rebuild!` listed on the github link.

Problem is, I do not have the option to create a node on the top level with no parent (e.g. - There is no blank `<option>` in the form select). This is the select_tag I am using:

```
<%= select_tag 'parent_id', options_for_select(nested_set_options(Page) {|i| "#{'..' * i.level} #{i.name}" } ) %>
```

I'm a RoR newb so I'm unsure of how to make it so I can create a page on the top level. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a record at the root level, simply leave `parent_id` nil. You will need to add an option for that:

```
<%= select_tag 'parent_id', options_for_select(
      nested_set_options(Page) {|i| "#{'..' * i.level} #{i.name}" }.unshift(["No Parent", nil])
    ) %>
```

It's probably time to move this into a helper.

Comment: Thanks Adam! I'll look into making this into a helper, thanks for the heads up on that!

Comment: @jyoseph Now that I think of it, a better UI choice would probably be to keep the field disabled unless a user wishes to assign a parent. That would require a bit of JS.

Comment: Thanks again Adam. Only problem I ran into with this is when editing an existing record, the state is not saved (the original parent doesn't stay selected, instead the "No Parent" option is selected.

Comment: @jyoseph you have to tell `options_for_select` which value to select as the second parameter. [Documentation](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M002444)

Comment: fwiw, I also found that you can do `{:include_blank => true}`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite a good way do this via **unshift** method.
Use **:include_blank => true** instead.

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, nested_set_options(Page){|i| "#{'-' * i.level} #{i.name}" }, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
```